# MySQL command returns 0 results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add entries to my prestashop customization_field tables, one for each of our products. I wrote this command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test5 () BEGIN 
DECLARE a INT;
SET a = 1461;
WHILE (a <= 3185) DO insert into ps7h_customization_field values (DEFAULT, `a`, `1`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`);
SELECT a = a + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
```

1461 is the ID of the first product, 3185 is the ID of the last one. The structure of the table is:

```
id_customization_field int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT
id_product int(10)
type tinyint(1)
required tinyint(1)
is_module tinyint(1)
is_deleted tinyint(1)
tshirtecommerce tinyint(1)
```

I'd want a line for each product with product_id from 1461 to 3185, each with a new id_customization_field number. The command goes through, but it returns 0 results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second column `id_product` is INT, but you try to insert `a`. Maybe that? Oh, and quotes should be `"` or `'` as \` is column name escape symbol

Comment: Why mix styles set a = , select a = ??

Comment: `SELECT a = a + 1;` should be `SET a = a + 1;`

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* You use backticks in ```values (DEFAULT, `a`, `1`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0`)``` instead of single quote chars over string literal values ('a', 1 and 0s). So this instructs the server that this is not values but columns names. But the table is not specified, and the error `Unknown column name 'a'` occures. Procedure fails. PS. For numeric literal values none quote chars needed.

Comment: With all these changes the command runs but it still returns 0 results, at least in phpmyadmin. I ran it in HeidiSQL and now it tells me "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2" - line 2 being ```DECLARE a INT;```

Comment: There is no evidence that you are setting delimiters..

Comment: ```DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test55 () BEGIN
DECLARE a INT;
SET a = 1461;
WHILE (a <= 3185) DO
insert into ps7h_customization_field  (a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SET a = a + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;```

Like this? It gives me a syntax error near 1, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Not quite you lost VALUES and the value a in the values clause is a string and  needs to be single quoted.

Comment: Whoops.

```DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test552 () BEGIN
DECLARE a INT;
SET a = 1461;
WHILE (a <= 3185) DO
insert into ps7h_customization_field VALUES ('a', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SET a = a + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;```

0 results. I'm so lost lmao.

Comment: I cannot see any substantive difference from my answer which does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key,col1 varchar(1),col2 varchar(1),col3 varchar(1),col4 varchar(1),col5 varchar(1),col6 varchar(1));

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p() 
BEGIN 
DECLARE a INT;
SET a = 5;
WHILE a <= 5 DO 
    insert into t values (null, 'a', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0');
    set a = a + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$
delimiter ;

call p();

select * from t;

+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | a    | 1    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

NB tested in heidisql.

Comment: That's a breakthrough, it was missing the call function. I don't think I can drop the table, since it was generated by prestashop and I'd assume it needs INT (unless there's no difference?). Now it worked but it didn't stop at the number I wanted it to, it just kept going up. (I'm doing this on a backup so it's ok)

Comment: The drop is purely for testing against a test table t. please include the columns you are inserting values to in the insert statement ie (insert into t(id,col1,col2..) values (null..). And you are passing a value of a but there are no character columns in your table definition so why?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g9QDuxbNz5aqVAwTPEFuFP/0 which inserts 5 rows as expected.

Comment: Okay, I got it, seems that other than the syntax errors i was simply missing the call function. Here's the full command ```DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test12345() BEGIN
DECLARE a INT;
SET a = 1461;
WHILE a <= 3185 DO
insert into ps7h_customization_field (id_customization_field, id_product, type, required, is_module, is_deleted, tshirtecommerce) VALUES (DEFAULT, a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SET a = a + 1;
END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
call test12345();```
Somehow it also told me it returned 0 results but it did work so, whatever. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backtics, don't assign value to autoincrement column  and assign  proper value to the columns  (the value `a` with backtics  is not a int but a column name )

```
insert into ps7h_customization_field
          ( id_product, type, required,is_module,is_deleted,tshirtecommerce)  
 values (a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this assign 1 to id_product, when I want it to be numbers from 1461 to 3185?

Comment: answer  updated .. using a (without backtics) for Id_product

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT should be a SET and you don t need the DEFAULT if its an AutoIncrement and the backticks are not required for the numerics, you dont actually need them round the `a` either, but it does not hurt.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test5 () 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE a INT;
    SET a = 1461;
    WHILE (a <= 3185) 
        DO insert into ps7h_customization_field values (`a`, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SET a = a + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: This also returns 0 results. Curious. The INSERT INTO command by itself works perfectly though. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to MySQL so I'm quite confused what I should be doing differently - the info about SET vs SELECT and the backticks is super helpful though.